# `poetry install` using packages on my system?

Tags: python, nixos, python-poetry

I'm still getting used to poetry so I'm hoping that I'm doing something wrong. For some reason, after running `poetry install`, it looks like not all the packages that I depend on end up in the virtual environment. See the below output:

```
$ poetry run pip show boto3
Name: boto3
Version: 1.18.29
Summary: The AWS SDK for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/boto/boto3
Author: Amazon Web Services
Author-email: None
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /home/stian/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/some_virtualenv-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: s3transfer, jmespath, botocore
Required-by: moto

$ poetry run pip show pluggy
Name: pluggy
Version: 0.13.1
Summary: plugin and hook calling mechanisms for python
Home-page: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pluggy
Author: Holger Krekel
Author-email: holger@merlinux.eu
License: MIT license
Location: /nix/store/l2i2x3g16g6dbwsw4iii614dh3xqgg9m-python3.8-pluggy-0.13.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: tox, pytest
```

Why does this happen? I'm using NixOS, but I'm hoping that's not the cause. To be clear: What I wish is for the "Location" for the `pluggy` package to also be within the "/home/stian/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/some_virtualenv-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages", as it is for the `boto3` package.

Comment: if possible, try not to mix pip and poetry. and if you do, run `poetry run python -m pip ...` to make sure that the right pip is used. But in this case, `poetry show --tree` should give you a nice overview over you environment, is the error also visible in there?

Comment: Thanks for commenting! There's only a single thing I've installed with pip directly, and that's poetry. After that, I've only used poetry. `poetry show --tree` shows me that pluggy is a dependency of pytest, which I have a dev dependency on.

Comment: A theory is that something else installed `pluggy` on my system (as you said - probably nix). However, I don't want poetry to use that. I want poetry to put all packages into the virtual environment.

Comment: is your output for `poetry run python -m pip show pluggy` the same?